# selenium testing in cakephp with phpunit

Tags: php, selenium, cakephp, phpunit

I want to learn about ui testing with selenium in phpunit. I had phpunit installed on my cakephp project, and it was running perfectly. Then I decided to install selenium following the steps described in https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html (i installed selenium in my project with the following command `$ php composer.phar require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium: ">=1.2"`. Now after starting the selenium server with its jar file, I have been trying to run the example test provided in the link above, but I am receiving the following error:

> $ vendor/bin/phpunit
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in
>   /var/www/html/ujols/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php
>   on line 97

Seems like the error is related to the Selenium2TestCase.php file that was installed with the composer. This is how the Selenium2TestCase.php file starts:

```
abstract class PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
```

Is there anyone here who managed to install selenium on cakephp or any other php framework? I would be super grateful if you could help me fix the problem

EDIT the sample test case i ve been trying to run to check if selenium is working:

PlainviewTest.php

```
<?php

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertEquals('Example WWW Page', $this->title());
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: noticed that I was actually looking at phpunit 3.7 manual while i had version 6 installed...  Does anyone have a link for the installation manual for selenium in phpunit6?

Comment: I don't think there is any, given that it's not yet compatible. **https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/pull/404**

Comment: @ndm thank you for your comment! How about facebook's php-webdriver? https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver i tried implementing it, but I cannot figure out how to run the test

Comment: Check out the docs [**Testing framework integration**](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#testing-framework-integration) section, besides the more sophisticated integration via Steward, there's also some very basic manual PHPUnit integration example. The webdriver library itself has no "testing functionality", it's just a connection to Selenium that you can use in any PHP script you want.

Comment: @ndm thank you so much for sharing it!!!! I have installed it and I am trying to run their example test asserting  w3.org  title, but when i run the test it says ` [ERROR] Testcases executed: 1 (fatal: 1) `, the log file is empty.. here is my file https://gist.github.com/nodirashidov/176a76d46031fe6f4063f6fb0834d838

Comment: forgot to mention that i followed this https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward

Comment: the `steward results` command prints `Testcases (1 total): prepared: 0, running: 0, done: 1 (passed: 0, failed: 0, fatal: 1)
Tests (0 total): started: 0, done: 0 (passed: 0, failed or broken: 0, skipped or incomplete: 0)
` i dont know what fatal here means, it doesnt say anyting about it

Comment: Check the selenium server output...

Comment: @ndm thank you so much for your help, I finally figured it out with your advice and now everything is working great!!! I am really loving this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a way to get selenium integrated with phpunit in my app with a lot of help from @ndm, here are the steps:

Follow the easy installation steps here - [Testing with Selenium WebDriver + PHPUnit](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward#1-install-steward)

*Make sure your new ui-tests are not in the same folder with unit tests, I had mine in the same folder and kept getting fatal errors.

*If running the `./vendor/bin/steward run staging firefox` command returns an error, then change firefox to chrome. If you still keep getting error (like I did), install chromedriver and run again. It should work.

It was really worth all the effort.

Comment: one more thing, if you want to set this up inside a php framework, then you should create a new separate folder in your project (as it says in the installation manual), and init a new composer there instead of using the existing phpunit of the framework. Otherwise the selenium will clash with regular phpunit tests and will keep exiting with fatal errors